# Align an icon horizontally to image whose width vary with only CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have a image whose size varies and an icon. I want align the icon horizontally to the image like this:

[image: Example image]

**UPDATE:**

Add a jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/p20qj06u/ . I replaced the icon with `<div class="icon">icon</div>`. I have to keep the image in this position(floating to right), then put the "icon" in middle of the image.

Comment: *One is floating left and the other is floating right to a container.* Won't be able to solve your issue unless you provide some code from your end

Comment: Please add a jsfiddle or an example of your code.

Comment: Thanks Tony, just posted an answer. Hope it works for you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Given the requirements you can add both images in one container you
   can call `.img-wrapper`
2. Apply `clear:both;` to the whole container .img-wrapper which is
       `float: right`.
3. Then `display:block;` on the icon and `margin:0 auto;`

**DEMO** http://jsfiddle.net/a_incarnati/p20qj06u/2/

```
           .container .img-wrapper {
                float: right;
            }
            .icon{
                clear:both; 
                display:block; 
                margin:0 auto;
            }
```

```css
.container .img-wrapper {
    float: right;
}
.icon{
    clear:both; 
    display:block; 
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="img-wrapper"><img  src="http://7xi5mk.com1.z0.glb.clouddn.com/FivlNV1GzShuj6lGpdCNip_6BYP8" alt="" />
        <img class="icon" src="http://placehold.it/20x20" alt="" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to center the icon with

```
text-align: center;
```

Unless the containing element isn't set to

```
display: block;
```

If that doesn't solve it, I suggest providing a snippet of an example so that we can clearly see the issue and how to resolve it :)

Comment: Yep, that's pretty much what I was going to say.. so here is a fiddle I prepared earlier... http://jsfiddle.net/kd83ksk4/

Comment: Done with the updating

Comment: @Tony Here is a solution you need to contain the image and the icon in a div and float that element not the image here is a jsfiddle example

https://jsfiddle.net/p20qj06u/3/

Comment: The icon will always be in the center of the div with a class of .float

Answer (score 0):

Create one div as container. Center content, set container width (% or px).

**UPDATE:** (with float: left;) https://jsfiddle.net/sa1axf46/2/

html

```
<div class="container">
    <img src="#" alt="img">
    <div class="icon">ico</div>
</div>
```

css

```
.container {
    text-align: center;
}
.container img {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}
.container .icon {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the icon inside the image's div and set the icon margins to auto.

```
<div class="image">
<div class="icon"></div>
</div>

.icon {
Left:0;
Right:0;
Margin-left:auto;
Margin-right:auto;
}
```